# mxml inheritance in Flex. how works "instanceof" and "is"?

Tags: apache-flex, inheritance, subclass, instanceof

Earlier i used following structure:

```
Canvas -> Screen1
Canvas -> Screen2
```

When I feel need in common logic in my application I do next:

```
Canvas -> Screen
Screen -> Screen1
Screen -> Screen2
```

So when I try to apply it in my code

```
if(child is Screen){
    return child.localToGlobal(new Point()).x;
}
```

It is not works!
When I see in debugger, child have type "Screen2", but "child is Screen" returns false to me (and "child instanceof Screen" too).
When I apply compiler key: "-keep-generated-actionscript" I can see Screen2-generated.as and it's contains

```
public class Screen3 extends screens.Screen
```

Thanks in advance
Sorry for my ugly english=)

Comment: I don't understand your structure.  Do you mean Screen1 extends Canvas?

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is with this specific name - there already is a class called Screen (in flash.display - http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/Screen.html), and Flex checks if it's an instance of the original screen.

You can try two things:

1) Rename your Screen class to CustomScreen and try it again.

2) Check if the child is an instance of your class by referencing it full path eg. `if (child is screens.Screen)`

Comment: Yeah!! Thanks for thinking about it!